# Android networking simple app

Tags: android, http, networking

App works(api 23 tested also kitkat tested), but nothing shows, it should show picture(download it and put it in view). Since I am not getting any error, I am lost. I am looking from android beginner book for code, and they suggest apps to be tested on 4.0(icecream) but there is no recommended build in android studio for that version. Is it not working because of some change in how android works with HTTP and networking in latest APIs?

```
public class NetworkingActivity extends Activity {

ImageView img;

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
        throws IOException
{
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
    try{
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("Networking", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;
}

private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.d("NetworkingActivity", e1.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return bitmap;
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return DownloadImage(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        img.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://www.mayoff.com/5-01cablecarDCP01934.jpg");

}
}
```

Here is logcat:

[image: logcat]

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="metropolitan.com.desetopredavanjeprotokoli10">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity class:

```
package metropolitan.com.desetopredavanjeprotokoli10;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Smor"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: R.layout.activity_main i need this =.=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are beginer I suggest your learn how to use framework 
There a lot of benefit using framework if not you will need to implement some complex code for handling such as caching,resizing,avoiding memory crash,handling for almost all API which you are facing  etc.

For image download i suggest

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)(which i suggest most)

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

For normal Http request

[Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

You can us Volley to download image as well. When you start learning it is kind a hard to understand but after u really get understading I promise you will not wan to use regular HTTPURLConnection to handle any HTTP Request

If you need upload with progress please let me know I will give add the code as well although it is much complicated.

Edited:

So far I have been test out your code it work perfectly fine.I would like to add it for you.

MainActivity

```
    ImageView img;

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException
    {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;

        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
                Log.d("asd","OK");
            }else{
                Log.d("asd","error");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("Networking", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            Log.d("in", String.valueOf(in));
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.d("NetworkingActivity", e1.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Log.d("aSD","ASD");
            return DownloadImage(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
            img.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://www.mayoff.com/5-01cablecarDCP01934.jpg");

    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/img"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Last add this to manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Result
[image]

If it really not working consider check your emulator or device network connection.

Comment: Hmm, tnx for this. I will check those for sure. Also in this log, do you know what can cause picture to not be shown? Tnx again for directions, I will start learning from them as soon as I finish this error with app. This app is homework so I kinda need to finish it.

Comment: @Beansolder I have tested your code code work fine can you added your XML as well?

Comment: @Beansolder LOL sorry for misunderleading I mean MainActivity XML file

Comment: I made mistake, haahha. :D

Comment: Hmmm no, still dont wok. But thank you so much for your help. I will try on different PC later, maybe this one have some problem with network.

Comment: Omg. I just noticed that I had two classes, one blank and it was calling always that first. Hahahahahah I cant belive this. 